# How to stop/kill "usr/share/python usr/share/apport/apport"

Tags: process, apport, kill

I have this process

```
"usr/share/python usr/share/apport/apport"
```

I cannot kill it by PID as the PID is changing to fast as the process keep restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo service apport stop
```

in a Terminal.

You can disable Apport by changing the line

```
enabled=1
```

to

```
enabled=0
```

in `/etc/default/apport`